# MySQL Select and Order by with a Limit that can change

Tags: sql, mysql

So I have the table:

```
id       uid       points       gameid
--------------------------------------
1        34        50           2
2        12        40           2
3        45        30           2
4        40        30           2
5        23        20           2
```

So I my goal is to get the top three players based on points.  So in the event uid 40 above had 20 pts the following query would work for me:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE gameid = 2 ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 3
```

But this only works when the top three people have different points.  I need a way to get the top three players but select more if points are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t JOIN (
    SELECT points
    FROM table r
    WHERE r.gameid = 2
    ORDER BY r.points DESC
    LIMIT 3
) tr ON t.points = tr.points
WHERE t.gameid = 2
```